# mobile app notification is out of sync

Tags: bug, notifications, android-app

this morning got around 10 notifications from yesterday, which I was already notified (and ack) about on web-app

V 1.0.43 on android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a [Redis upgrade](https://twitter.com/stackstatus/status/487443191608926208) this morning; there were [other problems too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236388/stubborn-24-in-the-topbar-that-wont-go-away).

This is almost certainly related.